# polymer on-hold event is far too short, is there a way to lengthen it?

Tags: polymer

I'm working on implementing a hold event in my web-app for holding a post to generate a dialog with a link to that post that can be copied and shared. It's doable, and it works, but the `on-hold` event seems to be only 200ms of holding, and that's far too short if you're slowly scrolling while reading and you suddenly end up with a dialog popping up because you didn't scroll fast enough to bypass the `on-hold` event. Does anyone know what script I'd need to change or where to look? I've googled as much as I care to over the last hour and people seem to be using `on-tap` more than `on-hold` and I've not found any documentation on changing hold length. I looked in polymer.js and found

```
...
 var hold = {
// wait at least HOLD_DELAY ms between hold and pulse events
HOLD_DELAY: 200,
// pointer can move WIGGLE_THRESHOLD pixels before not counting as a hold
WIGGLE_THRESHOLD: 16,
....
```

and played around with that, did not reflect any change in using `on-hold` or `on-holdpulse`

Anything helps at this point.

Edit: I've now finished the `on-hold` functionality for my news posts for my web-app in a separate test file. Still just need to find out if I can lengthen the `on-hold` time so I can actually implement the new functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work before when I was editing `HOLD_DELAY` in `polymer.js` but while playing with it tonight at work, setting it to 1000 did affect the hold length for `on-hold` events in my script. Maybe I was too tired to realize I hadn't saved or something when I was playing with it at home. Either way, I have my solution now.